# Swift constraint autosize label width

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, autolayout, constraints

This is my code to make UILabel autosize:

```
        gmatesLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: homeButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        gmatesLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gmatesUniversitySeparatorView.leadingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
        gmatesLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
//        gmatesLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gmatesLabel.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5)
        gmatesLabel.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, for: .horizontal)
```

Also I've tried this code :

```
gmatesLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: gmatesLabel.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 150).isActive = true
```

But the problem the labels always shrinked, what did I missed here ?

**Update**
I've added the leadingAnchor

```
gmatesLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

And this the function to set my label :

```
fileprivate func setCommonGmatesText(_ count: Int ) {

    let commonGmatesString   =  NSMutableAttributedString(string: "\(count)", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : Font.boldFont22, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Color.lightGray])
    commonGmatesString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\(NSLocalizedString("commonGmates", comment: "How much common gmates we got"))", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : Font.regularFont14, NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Color.lightGray]))
    gmatesLabel.attributedText = commonGmatesString
    gmatesLabel.sizeToFit()
}
```

[image]

Comment: why is there no leading anchor? you can define a leading anchor and define is as bigger than 5 for instance. If needed the label will grow to that size, if not ( because the text is not long enough), it will fit just the text

Comment: @Ocunidee I didn't add `leadingAnchor` because my view will be pined `top-right` and defining `height-width`  will be enough no need to add other constraint. Using storyboard this way works fine but programmatically I don't know why it didn't worked!

Comment: here you want the width to resize so you can't set the width, just the height. To make sure you label will not be bigger than it's superview, you should set a leading anchor that is equal or bigger to something like 8pt (usual margin size). You're label will resize. Maybe a screenshot would help to see your exact problem

Comment: @Ocunidee I've added the leading anchor but always getting same result check my update

Comment: I can think of several things: Where do you add your text in you label? You should do a yourLabel.sizeToFit() after adding text to it and you should also define the lineBreakMode: yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

Comment: @Ocunidee I've a background function that get some data from server then it set the label.

Comment: are my two suggestions changing anything?

Comment: @Ocunidee yep I think the issue was I've to set the `leadingAnchor` and `lineBreakMode` thank you :)

Comment: I'll write it as an answer and you can accept ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set a leadingAnchor to your label (greater or equal to 8pt for instance) so that the label doesn't grow bigger that it's superview.

You should also set the lineBreakMode:

```
yourLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```